# Getting Urlsessiontask failed with error: the request timed out with blank screen RxSwift in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift, sweetalert

I am using RxSwift in swift. When my server is close it shows below error with blank screen. I have used a alert. But I have to click too many time to close the alert here is the error

[image]

I have implemented RxSwift  below like

1. Data Model

   ```
     struct LoginDto : Decodable {

       let outCode: String
       let outMessage: String

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case outCode = "outCode"
           case outMessage = "outMessage"

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           outCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .outCode) ?? ""
           outMessage = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .outMessage) ?? ""

       }
   }
   ```
2. Common Error handling

   ```
    import RxSwift
    import Alamofire
     class ErrorViewModel {
       static let shared = ErrorViewModel()
       let publishSubject = PublishSubject<ErrorResponse>()
       var errorResponse: Observable<ErrorResponse> {
           return publishSubject.asObservable()
       }

      // private init() {}
   }
   ```
3. View Model

   ```
   import RxSwift
   import Alamofire
   class LoginViewModelV{

   private let loginSubject = PublishSubject<LoginDto>()
   var LoginResponse: Observable<LoginDto> {
       return loginSubject.asObservable()
   }

    func doLogin(`var` parameters: [String: Any]) {

           AF.request("htt://myurl/login", method: .post, parameters:parameters,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: "myheader")

               .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
               .responseDecodable(of: LoginDto.self) { [weak self] response in

                   switch response.result {
                   case .success:
                       switch response.response!.statusCode {
                       case 200:
                           if let v_response = response.value {
                                 self?.loginSubject.onNext(v_response)
                           }
                       default:
                           let ex =  ErrorHandling.exception(statusCode:response.response?.statusCode)
                           ErrorViewModel.shared.publishSubject.onNext(ex)
                       }
                   case .failure(let error):
                       let ex =  ErrorHandling.exception(error: error,statusCode:response.response?.statusCode)
                       ErrorViewModel.shared.publishSubject.onNext(ex)

                   }

               }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Here ViewController

   ```
    import UIKit
    import RxSwift
    class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

   var loginViewModel = LoginViewModelV()    
   private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       doLogin()
       observeEvents()
   }

   func observeEvents(){
       self.loginViewModel.LoginResponse
           .subscribe(onNext: { response in
               // here is login

           })
           .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

       ErrorViewModel.shared.publishSubject.subscribe(onNext: { err in
           Custom_Progress_bar.hide()
           /***
            I have use here sweet alert
            */
        //   Custom_Sweet_alert.show_error_message(messsage: err.message)

       }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
   }

   func doLogin(){

       let parameters: [String: Any] = [
           "userId": "myuserId",
           "passowrd": "mypasswor"
       ]

       loginViewModel.doLogin(var:parameters)
    }

   }
   ```

when server is off,  observeEvents method LoginViewController in  alert shows with blank screen. I have use ErrorViewModel to get all common error like network or others. What is the wrong of my code? Please help to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem here is that your `ErrorViewModel.publishSubject` is emitting more than once. You will have to track that down.

But in general, you are working way too hard here. Let's simplify your code by using my Cause_Logic_Effect library. You can import the library through Cocoapods or SPM.

```
import Cause_Logic_Effect
import RxSwift
import UIKit

struct LoginDto: Decodable {
    let outCode: String
    let outMessage: String
}

class LoginViewModelVI {
    static func doLogin(parameters: [String: Any]) -> Observable<LoginDto> {
        Observable.create { observer in
            AF.request("htt://myurl/login", method: .post, parameters:parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: "myheader")
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
                .responseDecodable(of: LoginDto.self) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        if let value = response.value, response.response!.statusCode == 200 {
                            observer.onSuccess(value)
                        } else {
                            observer.onError(ErrorHandling.exception(statusCode:response.response?.statusCode))
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        observer.onError(ErrorHandling.exception(error: error,statusCode:response.response?.statusCode))
                    }
                }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    let userIdField = UITextField()
    let passwordField = UITextField()
    let loginButton = UIButton()
    let activityTracker = ActivityTracker()
    let errorRouter = ErrorRouter()
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bind()
    }

    func bind() {
        loginButton.rx.tap
            .withLatestFrom(Observable.combineLatest(userIdField.rx.text, passwordField.rx.text))
            .flatMapFirst { [activityTracker, errorRouter] userId, password in
                LoginViewModelVI.doLogin(parameters: [
                    "userId": "myuserId",
                    "passowrd": "mypasswor"
                ])
                .trackActivity(activityTracker)
                .rerouteError(errorRouter)
            }
            .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                // here is login
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        errorRouter.error
            .subscribe(onNext: { err in
                /***
                 I have use here sweet alert
                 */
                //Custom_Sweet_alert.show_error_message(messsage: err.message)
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

        activityTracker.isActive
            .subscribe(onNext: { isActive in
                if isActive {
                    Custom_Progress_bar.show()
                } else {
                    Custom_Progress_bar.hide()
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```